# Can you change a setting in the Foo.settings file at run-time?

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have the following code that determines if it's the first time the user opens the app. If it is, a file dialog shows, and then it's supposed to change the setting to false, so it doesn't happen after that one time.

```
    public void VerifyIfFirstTimeRun()
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTimeUse == true)
        {
            LocateWoWFolder();
            Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTimeUse = false;
        }                        
    }
```

In the last line, I receive the following error:

> Error 1   Property or indexer 'CDLauncher.Properties.Settings.FirstTimeUse' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

How can I do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you really indent your code that way, or is that a typo? I've never seen code with the method header at less of an indent than the brackets.

Comment: Typo of the post system in the site :P

Comment: Thanks. I'll feel free to fix those up, in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out you can indeed change the .settings at run-time, but only setting in the "User" scope.

So if you're trying to make a setting that does X only when the first time the app opens, you can do the following:

```
public void VerifyIfFirstTimeRun()
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTimeUse == true)
    {
        //Do something here.

        //Change first time usage Bool to false
        Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTimeUse = false;

        //Save your changes, and you're done!
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }                        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The scope of your setting is probably set to Application. Set it to User, you will be able to modify it.